# Weird error with unicode-math and math subscript

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode-math, typefaces

I stumbled across what appears to be a very weird error when using unicode-math and lualatex/xelatex.

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test subscript: $\mathbf{a}_\mathbf{b}$. 

\end{document}
```

Everything compiles and we get the expected result. Now add `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and it doesn't compile anymore: I get the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \__um_group_begin: 
l.7 Test subscript: $\mathbf{a}_\mathbf
                                       {b}$.
```

The stangest is that I have no problem if I put `$a_\mathbf{b}$` or `$\mathit{a}_\mathbf{b}$` or whatever as long as it is not the same *face/shape* on the base line and in the subscript.

What am I missing here that would explain this 'bug' ?

Of course, everything is fixed if I do `$\mathbf{a}_{\mathbf{b}}$`. The thing is I inherited a big LaTeX project with a lot of macros like `\ZZ` for `\mathbb Z`, or `\id` for `\mathord{\mathrm{id}}` etc. and the source is full of `\id_\ZZ` and the likes. The project has been compiled with pdflatex up until now and I'm trying to convert that to lualatex+unicode to have more freedom with the fonts and stuff. I don't want to change manually every macros (or even worse, every usage in the source).

Comment: That is just too bad, as far as I remember `unicode-math` requires `{...}` for these things. The fact that `$\mathbf{a}_\mathbf{b}$` works on the old systems is just pure luck and sadly some authors have adused this luck.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, but then how does it happen that $a_\mathbf{b}$ works like a charm? It is only when using the same typefaces that the bug is happening...

Comment: `_\mathbf{b}` is wrong syntax. In some cases you are not "punished" because of some side effects but you can't rely on it. Add braces.

Comment: @Pece I got no error with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: Presumably because the old definition is similar to `{{... b}}` then the extra brace layer can make `_` pick up the whole thing, other implementations does not work like that, thus relying on `$\mathbf{a}_\mathbf{b}$` is not advisable.

Comment: @javadr you probably need to add `\usepackage{unicode-math}` to the mwe.

Comment: @daleif I did it with/without `unicode-math`, but I got the same result without any errors. `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991  (TeX Live 2019)` and `LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)` under Fedora 31 linux.

Comment: `x_\mathbf{b}` has *never* been a supported syntax; it *may* work or not. Learn to type `x_{\mathbf{b}}` and you'll be OK forever. For the `_\ZZ` problem, just fix with `\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb{Z}}}` and similarly for the other commands.

Comment: @egreg I did learn that and *I* am doing it. As I said, I picked up a project where people are not that thourough... Are they any unexpected error that can occur if I change a `\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}` to `\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}` ? Of course, `\ZZ` is used in other context that subscript, and I wouldn't like this modification to change the spacing or whatever.

Comment: @egreg, just saw the edit on your comment, thanks !